# Word order in: "We from equation (A) obtain (B)." or "We due to a+b=c find that (C) holds."

Tags: grammaticality

Given the following sentences that verbalise logical implications,

- *"We from equation (A) obtain (B)."*
- *"We due to a+b=c find that (C) holds."*,

would you say that the words in those sentences are ordered correctly?

(Or would it be better to write *"We obtain (B) from equation (A)."* or *"We find that (C) holds due to a+b=c."*, even though in these latter formulations the premise appears less immanent?)

Comment: *From equation (A), we obtain (B).* or *Due to a+b=c, we find that (C) holds.* The subject doesn't have to come first in English sentences, and these are more natural word orders than the ones you suggest. (And *we* as a subject is so innocuous and unassuming that there's no reason that you need to contort the more natural word order to put it first.)

Comment: That settles it, thank you very much!

Comment: I beg to differ. This is a question and answer site. Comments are not answers and settle nothing. Answers in comments break the fundamental model on which Stack Exchange is based.

Comment: I can't think of a single S-PP-V  for S-V-PP example that sounds idiomatic. 'Correct' involves more than grammar (Orwell's Sixth being the master rule. If you can find a proper arbiter of 'sounds natural'.)

Comment: @Edwin: I can find examples of S-PP-V on the web: *The Agent, unless specifically disclosed otherwise, represents the seller in any transaction for the sale of a home.*  Does it sound idiomatic?  Maybe if you're a lawyer...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth your general guidance seems to hold reasonably well for adverbial PPs but not adjectival PPs: "The man in the car beckoned to me." - *The man, in a strange way, beckoned to me."

Comment: @Peter I'd call that a conjunction usage with conjunction reduction.

Comment: @Greybeard. You're right that certain types are fine. 'The man in the car' is of course S in your example, which is therefore inappropriate. In the second, the PP is an adjunct, non-defining/non-restrictive. In fact, the sentence is ambiguous: I'd say the 'sentence adverbial' reading is the default.  There is more of a 'requirement' (this is where the 'mandatory, complement' debate gets tricky with OP's examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write these as:

> From equation (A), we obtain (B),
> Due to a+b=c, we find that (C) holds.

The subject doesn't have to come first in English sentences, and these are more natural word orders than the ones you suggest. (And *we* as a subject is so innocuous and unassuming that there's no reason that you need to contort the more natural word order to put it first.)

I believe your suggestions:

> We from equation (A) obtain (B),
> We due to a+b=c find that (C) holds.

would actually be classified as grammatical, but their word orders are rather unnatural, so unless you have a very good reason for putting a adverbial phrase between the subject and the verb, you should avoid it.